# Angular $resource not passing the full URL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

SELF EDIT:

I am not sure what the correct protocol here is when I mess up a post...  But I messed this one up.  The log statement I noted below is actually coming from the other correct execution of the bill detail page.  It is correct.

I do not see a log message for the billImages request I am trying to make.  I do get some data returned by that service call though, and I'm still looking into why.

Apologies to any kind soul who invested brain matter into thinking about my faulty post.

---

I am new to AngularJS and struggling to figure this out.

I am using Angular's $resource to call a NodeJS webservice I am also writing.

My service code:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    //BillImages service used for communicating with the billImages REST endpoints
    angular.module('bills').factory('BillImages', billImagesService);

    function billImagesService($resource) {
        return {
            getBillImages: getBillImages
        };

        function getBillImages(){
            return $resource(
                'bills/:billId/billImages', 
                {billId: '@_id'},
                {getBillImages: {method: 'GET'}}
            );
        }
    }
}());
```

When the server gets the request, it comes in with:

```
GET /bills/55551963b969c76c241e8e4c 304 47.072 ms - -
```

My problem is the "/billImages" portion of the URL is being lopped off somewhere between the service call and the server!!!  Why?

I am trying to create a page that shows the details for a single bill, but also shows a list of billImages that are children of the bill.

Here is the controller code that is calling the angular service (if it matters),

```
// Find the latest bill images for the current bill
$scope.findCurrentImages = function() {
    $scope.billImages = BillImages.getBillImages({
        billId: $stateParams.billId
    });
};
```

I'd appreciate both a solution and advice on improving my approach.

Comment: Can you see the request in firebug or chrome dev tools? Is it possible you're just printing the url wrong?

Comment: Tony, Yes, I did inspect the outbound URL in Chrome Dev Tools and validate the url received by the server.  The logging is taken care of something in the MEANJS framework I'm using and it correctly shows urls for all of the other calls being made.

Comment: Tony, your question got me thinking about logs and i discovered that the log message I saw was actually for the main part of the page.  I updated the question.  I'll  post back here if I see anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answer.

I'm still not clear on everything here, but switching the controller from:

```
$scope.findCurrentImages = function() {
    $scope.billImages = BillImages.getBillImages({
        billId: $stateParams.billId
    });
};
```

to:

```
$scope.findCurrentImages = function() {
    $scope.billImages = BillImages.query({
        billId: $stateParams.billId
    });
};
```

AND reverting by service back to the template provided by the MeanJS sample app:

```
angular.module('bills').factory('BillImages', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource(
            'bills/:billId/billImages/:billImageId', 
            {billId: '@_id'}, 
            {update: {method: 'PUT'}}
        );
    }
]);
```

Made the REST service calls start to happen again.